# Error in Jquery, Submit Button Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find the error in my jquery append code. All is appending except for the last line, which is to put a form and submit button at the bottom of the comment/reply that is posted.

The problem seem to be in the "profileformdiv".

> profile.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
>   position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.success (getprofilecomment.js:36)
>       at fire (jquery.js:3291)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3421)
>       at done (jquery.js:9533)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.js:9785)

```
$(function(){


var userName = $("#username").val();

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "api/getprofilecomment.php",
  type: "json",
  cache: false,
  success: function(profileComment)
  {
    var profileComment = JSON.parse(profileComment);
    for(var i = 0; i < profileComment.length; i++)
    {
      $("#usercommentdiv").append('<div class=' + '"' + 'profilecommentheader' + '"' + 'id=' + '"' + 'profilecommentheader' + '"' + 'name=' + '"' + 'profilecommentheader' + '"' + '>' + '</div>');
      $("#usercommentdiv").append('<div class=' + '"' + 'profilecommentdiv' + '"' + 'id=' + "'" + profileComment[i].profile_comment_id + "'" + 'name=' + '"' + 'profilecommentdiv' +  '"' + '>' + userName + ':' + profileComment[i].profile_comment + '</br>' + profileComment[i].time_added + '</div>');
      $("#usercommentdiv").append('<div class=' + '"' + 'profileuseriddiv' + '"' +  'id=' + '"' + profileComment[i].profile_user_id + '"' + 'name=' + '"' + 'profileuserid' + '"' + '</div>');
      $("#usercommentdiv").append('<div class=' + '"' + 'profileformdiv' + '"' + 'id=' + '"' + 'profileformdiv' + '"' + '>' + '<form type=' + "POST" + '>' + '<input type=' + "text" + 'id=' + "'" + "submit" + "'" + 'value=' + '"' + profileComment[i].profile_comment_id + '"' + '/>' + '<input type=' + "submit" + 'id=' + "submitreply" + 'onClick=' + "/api/postprofilereply.php" + 'value=' + "Reply" + "/>" + "</form>" + "</div>");
    };
}

});
});
```

Comment: `Unexpected token <` normally means that you've got HTML - most likely a badly handled unexpected error / exception that's pumping an HTML error page instead of a 500.

Comment: `type:'json'` is not valid, the `type` parameters is a synonym for `method` - perhaps you meant `dataType` - if that's the case then `profileComment` will already be json so `JSON.parse(json)` will also likely give an error.    Remove `var profileComment = JSON.parse(profileComment);`

Comment: you should probaly console.log profileComment before using JSON.parse to confirm wether the api is returning an json object or something else

Comment: I found the error. There were inconsistent parentheses.